# Google Analytics Search and Replace Filter

Tags: regex, google-analytics, analytics

I'm looking to create a filter in Google Analytics using a regular expression that will take an existing URL and remove a single character in that string. For example...

Existing URL:
/product.aspx?name= (contains an '=' at the end of the URL)

Desired URL:
/product.aspx?name (does NOT contain an '=' at the end of the URL)

I know where to enter the RegEx but I'm not sure what the correct 'Search String' and 'Replace String' should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Here is the "search" string:

^(.*)=

And here is the replace string:

\1

Google Analytics treats the contents inside a set of parentheses as a backreference. In this case, the contents of the first (and only) set of parentheses is backreference \1.